# How to disable output for a command in Symfony Console?

Tags: php, symfony, magento, symfony-console

I writing a module, actually a custom command in Magento 2. Magento 2 console application is proudly powered by **Symfony Console**, obviously. And my concernation is how to disable output from `$output` for specified command?

For example:

```
$setupUpgradeCommand = $this->getApplication()->find('setup:upgrade');

$setupUpgradeArguments = array(
    'command' => 'setup:upgrade',
    '--quiet' => true,
);

$setupUpgradeInput = new ArrayInput($setupUpgradeArguments);

$start = microtime(true);
$output->writeln('<info>Start upgrading module schemas...</info>');
$setupUpgradeCommand->run($setupUpgradeInput, $output);
$output->writeln('...............................<info>OK</info>');

// My long logic-code start from here....
```

Unfortunately, even I set `--quiet` to true, output of this command `setup:upgrade` still there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Insert the `Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput` class rather than the actual output.

Comment: @qooplmao I'd love your solution. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As answered in a comment.. although almost exactly the same as the answer by @toooni.

You can insert the `NullOutput` rather than inserting the actual output object supplied by the command.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;

$setupUpgradeCommand->run($setupUpgradeInput, new NullOutput());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use BufferedOutput:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

...

$setupUpgradeCommand->run($setupUpgradeInput, new BufferedOutput());
```

The usage is described here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/command_in_controller.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the logger and have this spewed on your CLI if you ask for it. You can read more about it in this (by now old) news post: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-show-logs-in-console

A full example where you can even format the output taken from the post:

```
services:
    my_formatter:
        class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Formatter\ConsoleFormatter
        arguments:
            - "[%%datetime%%] %%start_tag%%%%message%%%%end_tag%% (%%level_name%%) %%context%% %%extra%%\n"

monolog:
    handlers:
        console:
            type:   console
            verbosity_levels:
                VERBOSITY_NORMAL: NOTICE
            channels: my_channel
            formatter: my_formatter
```

You can find the documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html

Comment: This is a sexy way. But unfortunately, I don't want to add too much package to Magento composer.json...

Comment: You could simply copy the class if adding the package is too much overhead